# Elastic Search - How to get lost records

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

We have a 5 node, 16 shards ElasticSearch cluster across 5 servers, plus a routing server and a monitoring server

**Scenario**

A developer has accidentally deleted a number of documents from an index within the cluster. ES snapshots have not been set up, though through our VPS provider, each of the servers has regular server-wide backups, and we can spin up and down extra instances easily as necessary.  What is the fastest way to restore the lost records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no guarantee that those backups from a regular backup tool are useful, because they do not guarantee a consistent point-in-time snapshot.

You should not try to bring those backups into your production cluster, you can try to have a second cluster in your non-production environment and load those backups, but there is zero guarantee that this will work.

The fastest way would be reindexing from the original source I guess.